# Merge 2 matrices of the same size in R

Tags: r, matrix, merge

I have 2 matrices of exactly the same size (100 X 500). I would like to merge them into 1 matrix of the same size (100 X 500) Without loosing any information. I am not sure how to express this but here's what I have in my mind.

```
Matrix A
   A        B        C      D     ...
   E        F        G      H     ...
   .
   .
   .

Matrix B
   1        2        3      4     ...
   5        6        7      8     ...
   .
   .
```

The outcome I am looking forward to have is like this

```
Matrix C
   A-1        B-2        C-3      D-4     ...
   E-5        F-6        G-7      H-8     ...
   .
   .
```

Any function that can do this?? This is supposed to be some basic command but, I have never faced this issue before.
Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `paste` on your matrices :

```
m1 <- matrix(LETTERS[1:24],nrow=6,ncol=4)
m2 <- matrix(1:24,nrow=6,ncol=4)
matrix(paste(m1,m2,sep="-"),nrow=nrow(m1),ncol=ncol(m1))
```

Which will give :

```
     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] "A-1" "G-7"  "M-13" "S-19"
[2,] "B-2" "H-8"  "N-14" "T-20"
[3,] "C-3" "I-9"  "O-15" "U-21"
[4,] "D-4" "J-10" "P-16" "V-22"
[5,] "E-5" "K-11" "Q-17" "W-23"
[6,] "F-6" "L-12" "R-18" "X-24"
```

`paste` returns a vector instead of a matrix, that's why you have to cast the result back to a matrix by specifying its dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `interaction` here

```
    matrix(interaction(m1,m2,sep='-'),nrow=nrow(m1),ncol=ncol(m1))
     [,1]  [,2]   [,3]   [,4]  
[1,] "A-1" "G-7"  "M-13" "S-19"
[2,] "B-2" "H-8"  "N-14" "T-20"
[3,] "C-3" "I-9"  "O-15" "U-21"
[4,] "D-4" "J-10" "P-16" "V-22"
[5,] "E-5" "K-11" "Q-17" "W-23"
[6,] "F-6" "L-12" "R-18" "X-24"
```